# ¿Cómo puedo tener URL amigables en la parte admin con .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Quisiera hacer una consulta sobre un aspecto concreto de URL amigable que no me acaba de salir.

Tengo un proyecto Web que tiene una parte pública y otra privada, con esta estructura de directorios

proyecto/

- /admin
- /css
- /js
- /img
- index.php
- .htaccess

y en .Htaccess esta regla:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Dentro del directorio admin (que será la parte privada de la web) tengo otro index.php, que digamos arranca la página de inicio de la parte privada.

Con la parte publica no tengo problemas con las url amigables, me van bien, pero cuando accedo al directorio admin la url que me muestra es la siguiente:

```
proyecto/admin/?page=admin
```

cuando yo quiero que me muestre

```
proyecto/admin
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor, añade todo el código que tengas para poder dar una respuesta más acertada

Comment: No hay código de momento, solo la estructura de directorios, y los index,php, el proyecto esta vacío de momento, quería montar primero la estructura de carpetas y ver que las URL se obtienen de forma amigable

Comment: ¿Has probado a añadir en el directorio `admin` un .htaccess? Y usar la regla indicada para que se oculte lo demás. Prueba a buscar un poco por la red, ¡seguro que lo encuentras!

Comment: Es que si no hay código (las directivas de Apache también lo son, tal vez a eso  se refiere Lucía), como dices que "te va bien"? Y no es sólo una línea, en el .htaccess unas líneas podrían afectar otras.

Answer (score 0):

Bien no se como tienes las rutas 
pero creo que esto debería funcionar

```
[directorio/carpeta]/archivo php
admin/index.php
```

Puedes usar esta:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/index.php
```

o esta:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me ha funcionado